# How many islands in The End?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On average, how many outer islands are there in The End in bedrock editions (PE / windows 10) ?

I am mostly curious if it is finite or generates infinitely. If it's finite, then there is a limited number of end cities, and a limited number of shulkers and elytra. If I were to keep up a long term realm/server with many players, then eventually all the end cities would be already looted and it wouldn't be fun to go to the end anymore. Are my dreams crushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't figure a problem since the [community-run Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com) mentions in their article about [The End](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End):

> These outer islands generate infinitely, topped with a forest of chorus trees that may be harvested for its fruit.

Meaning that the answer to your question is no, your dreams won't be crushed as it does not have an end.

However, should you for any reason still wish to regenerate The End, all you need to do is access your server's files and delete the folder DIM1 (NOT DIM-1), as all informations about The End are stored there and its deletion means it will be freshly generated.